# Storing System Calls in C Programming

Tags: c, datetime

I have a C programme, which prints a timestamp as a string using the following line:

```
sprintf (scratch_buffer, "%s\0", dfr_time_date_strg);
```

This timestamp is always printed as UTC, but I would like to add the string of the calls `date +%z` and `date +%Z`.

The two timezone values can be called as such:

```
system("date +%z");
system("date +%Z");
```

But how can I assign these to `char` strings called `tz_offset` and `tz_name` so that the final timestamp print line is:

```
sprintf (scratch_buffer, "%s %s (%s)\0", dfr_time_date_strg, tz_offset, tz_name);
```

Comment: are you want to use output of `system("date +%z");` and other command?

Comment: Yes please.  So `+0100` and `BST` for example.

Comment: @DustinCook First of all, those are not "system calls" (that's something compeltely different), second, google `popen()`. **However, if you only need to format the current date,** then you'd be much better off just using `strftime()`.

Comment: You need to use popen for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the thing you are describing as "system call" is **not a system call,** only a call to the `system()` function. A system call is [something different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

As to your question: you have a [stereotypical XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). **You definitely do NOT want to grab the output of the `date` command.** ([That could be done using `popen()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c), but please don't.) You rather want to use the standard library:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    char buf[256];
    strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%Z", tm);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

The above snippet, when compiled and run, prints `CEST` for me.